# Set Console Output

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I recently came across this NPM package called "ora".
In the README.MD it has this gif:
[image: gif]

How do I print to the console without creating a new line?

Comment: Why don't you look at its code to see how it does it?

Comment: Yeah I've tried doing that. It has numerous dependecies and I believe it doesn't directley set the lines itself.

Comment: What they do in that demo is something like this: output "First text\r" (note "\r" -- "Carriage Return" symbol which moves cursor to start of the line, not usual "\n" -- "Line Feed" symbol which moves cursor to start of the next line), then some delay, then output "Second text\r", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They probably just use `process.stdout.write`:

```
process.stdout.write('whatever')
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It works and I will mark it as the answer in a few minutes.